# Prove convexity when the sign of the 2nd order derivative is difficult to determine

Tags: convex-analysis

Suppose that $$f(x) = \frac{e^x-1} {x(x+a)},$$ where $x>0$ and $a>0$, how to prove $f$ is convex in $x$? If it is not convex, do you have a counterexample?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). – Although, as a 3 year member of this site, you should know that :)

Comment: @coffeemath fixed.

Comment: it's not that bad. you just have to simplify the first derivative and you only have to differentiate the numerator of $f'(x)$ to get the sign of $f''(x)$.
You can make use of the fact that the product of two monotonically increasing and continuous functions is also monotonically increasing for $x \geq 0$

Comment: "you only have to differentiate the numerator of f′(x) to get the sign of f′′(x)." Care to elaborate, @okzoomer? I am not very good at math.

Comment: $\displaystyle f‘(x) = \frac{e^x(x^2+ax) - (e^x-1)(2x+a)}{x^2(x+a)^2} = \frac{e^x(x^2+(a-2)x - a) + 2x + a}{x^2(x+a)^2}$ the denominator is always non-negative

Comment: @okzoomer I wish I understood what you wrote, but I don't. How does it prove convexity?

Comment: @Adam I take back what I said about only differentiating the numerator. It has more stipulations than what I mentioned. Instead you should look to simplify by writing out $x(x+a)$ as $x^2 + ax$ and $x^2(x+a)^2$ as $x^4 + 2ax^3 + a^2x^2$ and proceed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131336/discussion-between-adam-and-okzoomer).

Answer (score 2):

Use brute force and group terms to have
$$f''(x)=\frac{A(x)\,a^2+B(x)\,a+C(x)}{x^3 (x+a)^3}$$ with
$$A(x)=e^x (x^2-2 x+2)-2$$$$B(x)=2x(e^x(x^2-3 x+3)-3)$$
$$C(x)=x^2( e^x(x^2-4 x+6)-6)$$ Show that these three terms are always positive for $x>0$.

Compute $\Delta=B^2(x)-4A(x)C(x)$ and show that is it always negative. If this is true, then $f''(x)>0 \quad \forall (a,x)$.